# Angular: Nested state not working in UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, multi-level

Multilevel nesting is not working in ui-router. I have added "ui-view" inside a template named as "tpl.hello.html" which is a template of state "home.hello". This "home.hello" state is a child state of "home" state. After that i've added following state in stateprovider:

```
 .state('home.hello.test', {
      url: '/test',
      templateUrl: 'tpl.hellonested.html'
 })
```

But this "home.hello.test" state does not load up inside "home.hello" state.

Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NbPsGLxs1l22CUyKgyrR?p=preview) for a look.

Comment: i tried your plunkr and its working just right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt see any problem, and based on your plunkr, your routes are

```
-Home
   *Home.Home1
      >Home.Home1.Test
   *Home.Home2
```

So if you go to **"Home.Home1"**, it will ***NOT*** load **"Home.Home1.Test"**,
but if you load **"Home.Home1.Test"**, it will also load all its parent states. Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/L9o5W0viXY8Ni12Nz4xT?p=preview) (just modified it a little).

Comment: i realized I just said the same thing with Tom Shen

Comment: Thanks for explaining with plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the wrong idea about nesting in ui-router.
The child state loads the parent state, not the otherway around.

In your own plunkr you can see the parent state (home.hello) is loaded in the child state (home.hello.test) if you click the link test.

The `<div ui-view></div>` just defines the position of the child view in the parent view. If you place it on top op your parent view, the child view will load on top of parent view, if you place it on bottom, it will load on bottom.

There is good documentation on this [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I know that child state loads the parent state, but my problem is related to multi-level nested states. So, "home.hello" is parent state of "home.hello.test" then why it does not render html.

Comment: It does render html, but only when you go to the child state. Click on your last link (to your child state) and it will render both your child html and parent html. Going to your parent state will not render your child html. That's how states work. Multi-level nested states is the same principle, just more layers.